# array in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have doubt in how to increase the order under NSLOg statement.
for e.g my code is

```
 int anBray[ ] = {0,5, 89, 34,9,189,9,18,9 34,89, 34,2,600,-2,0};

 int i;    

NSLog (@"Input:");

     for (i=0; i<sizeof(anBray)/sizeof(int); i++)
    NSLog(@ " anBray[i]= %i ",anBray[i]);
```

actually i am getting the output-:

```
                               anBray[i]=0                               
                               anBray[i]=5
                               anBray[i]=89.....and so on.
```

but how can i get output like this-:

```
                                 anBray[0]=0
                                 anBray[1]=5
                                 anBray[2]=89....and so on.
```

please any one help me thanks...

Comment: this - NSLog (@"anBray[%i]=%i", i, anBray[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed that for you:

```
for (i=0; i<sizeof(anBray)/sizeof(int); i++) {
   NSLog(@ " anBray[%d]= %d ",i,anBray[i]); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change  `NSLog(@ " anBray[i]= %i ",anBray[i],anBray[i]);`  to  `NSLog(@ " anBray[%i]= %i ",i,anBray[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
 for (i=0; i<sizeof(anBray)/sizeof(int); i++) {
   NSLog(@ " anBray[%d]= %d ",i,anBray[i]); 
 }
```

May this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<sizeof(anBray)/sizeof(int); i++)
    NSLog(@ " anBray[%d]= %i ",i,anBray[i]);
```