# array length in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392642/array-in-objective-c)

i have doubt about how to find the length of array.....

my code is

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void myFunction(int i, int*anBray);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int anBray[] = {0,5, 89, 34,9,189,9,18,99,1899,1899,18,99,189, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,89, 34,2,600,-2,0};
    int i;    

    NSLog (@"Input:");
    for (i=0; i<sizeof(anBray)/sizeof(int); i++)
        NSLog(@ " anBray[%i]= %i ",i,anBray[i]); 

    NSLog (@"Output");

    myFunction(i,anBray);

    return 0;

}

void myFunction(int i, int*anBray) {

    for ( i=0;  i<anBray; i++) {
        if ( anBray[i] == 0) {
            anBray[i] = anBray[i+1] - anBray[i]; 
        } else {
            anBray[i] = anBray[i] - anBray[i];
            anBray[i] = anBray[i+1] - anBray[i];
        }
        NSLog(@ " anBray[%i]= %i",i,anBray[i]); 

    }

}
```

in the function "void myFunction" it works but it gives garbage value too.how can it makes properly works?
plz help...

Comment: This question has almost nothing to do with Objective C and is more a C question. The only thing Objective C about it is you're using NSLog instead of printf(). Objective C arrays are typically done with NSArray from the foundation classes.

Comment: @Chris: thanks i have understand the topic

Answer (score 1):

The for(i = 0; i < anBray; i++) { line doesn't make sense. You're trying to compare a pointer with an integer.

To determine the size of an array you can do as you did in your main function with sizeof anBray/sizeof anBray[0] or sizeof anBray/sizeof (int) in your specific case.

However, in your myFunction function, you're accepting an int pointer, so you cannot get the size of the array the pointer points into. This int pointer points to the first element of anBray. That is, the following are equivalent:

```
myFunction(i, anBray);
myFunction(i, &anBray[0]);
```

Since you're unable to determine the array size from myFunction, you must either pass the size (actually element count, not size in bytes) or use a known sentinel value (e.g. -1) at the end of the array to detect it. You can then loop until you reach the end, example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int nelem, int *a) {
    int e;
    for (e = 0; e < nelem; e++) // Now the element count is known.
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", e, a[e]);
}

int main(void) {
    int x[] = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    // The number of elements in an array is its total size (sizeof array)
    // divided by the size of one element (sizeof array[0])
    // Here we pass it as the first argument to f()
    f(sizeof x / sizeof x[0], x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i don't exactly understand what r u trying to say ? please clarify again

Comment: I gave an example where you pass the size to the function. What don't you understand?

Comment: actually i am new in this site . my account have been blocked .please  i request from the author to reopen my blocked account. i will not mistake again .please....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, in any flavor of C, determine the size of an array (vs, say, an NSArray) declared with no dimension.  The information is simply not there to get.  An array is passed purely as a pointer to the first element, and there is no dimension information stored with the array or somehow passed with the pointer.

In languages like Java the array is itself an object, with a header that contains its dimension.  But in C an array is just an address to some space somewhere.

Comment: so how can i correct my code ?

Comment: @user1511571n -- Pass the dimension, use an NSArray, etc.

Comment: is there any way to pass the argument or dimension without NSArray

Comment: There *is* "dimension" information stored with the array. You can determine the number of elements in an array with sizeof array / sizeof array[0]. This is why in my answer, I demonstrate passing this to the function.

Comment: @ChrisYoung -- You are quite wrong.  What you're determining there is the DECLARED size of `array`, the variable.  There is no size information "stored with" the array.

Comment: @user1511571 -- You can pass the pointer to `array` and the size you (as the caller) know it to be, as separate parameters.

Comment: @HotLicks - Fair enough. I misunderstood and used poor wording. "stored with" was a poor choice.